# Aparecer dias da semana e horários apenas ser selecionado no datetimepicker

Tags: jquery

Estou utilizando o plugin datimepicker de https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ e está funcionando legal e configurado com a resposta do tópico [Horário específico para dia da semana no datetimepicker](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95514/hor%C3%A1rio-espec%C3%ADfico-para-dia-da-semana-no-datetimepicker)

Como eu faço para aparecer os horários somente ao selecionar um dos dias que tenha horários especificados

Por exemplo senão tiver nenhum horário no sábado

dayOfWeek[6] = { desc: "Sab", allowTimes: [] };

Então os horários de sábado não seria exibido, pois ele está sem nenhum horário definido, na resposta do tópico que citei acima ele exibe os horários.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: E se o usuário selecionar um sábado, que horário deverá aparecer no input, já que o datetimepicker sempre retorna um valor com dia, mês, ano, hora e minutos?

Answer (score 0):

Deixar a array vazia não funciona. Use a opção `timepicker` com o valor `false` que irá ocultar a coluna de horários para o dia da semana (ou mais de um dia) específico que você quiser.

Aproveitando o [exemplo do link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95535/8063) que você citou na pergunta, neste array de objetos onde cada índice corresponde a um dia da semana, basta você omitir a chave `allowTimes` do dia da semana onde você não quer que apareça a coluna para selecionar um horário:

```
var dayOfWeek = {};
dayOfWeek[0] = { desc: "Dom" };
dayOfWeek[1] = { desc: "Seg", allowTimes: ['07:00', '09:00', '11:00', '13:00', '15:00'] };
dayOfWeek[2] = { desc: "Ter", allowTimes: ['08:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00'] };
dayOfWeek[3] = { desc: "Qua", allowTimes: ['09:00', '11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00'] };
dayOfWeek[4] = { desc: "Qui", allowTimes: ['10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00'] };
dayOfWeek[5] = { desc: "Sex", allowTimes: ['11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00', '19:00'] };
dayOfWeek[6] = { desc: "Sáb" };
```

Repare que nos dias *Domingo* e *Sábado* (índices 0 e 6) não possuem a chave `allowTimes`.

> *A chave `desc` não tem utilidade prática aí, serve apenas como guia
> pra vc saber que dia da semana é aquele objeto. Você pode até dispensar ela, deixando, por exemplo, no caso de domingo e sábado, um objeto vazio tipo `dayOfWeek[0] = {};`*

O código nas opções do `datetimepicker` irá verificar se a chave `allowTimes` existe no dia da semana correspondente e ocultar ou não a coluna de horários.

**Obs.:** Adicionei um `if` (opcional) na função `onChangeDateTime` para exibir apenas a data (sem o horário) no `input` caso o dia selecionado seja um dos dias onde não há opção de horários.

Veja:

```js
var dayOfWeek = {};
dayOfWeek[0] = { desc: "Dom" };
dayOfWeek[1] = { desc: "Seg", allowTimes: ['07:00', '09:00', '11:00', '13:00', '15:00'] };
dayOfWeek[2] = { desc: "Ter", allowTimes: ['08:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00'] };
dayOfWeek[3] = { desc: "Qua", allowTimes: ['09:00', '11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00'] };
dayOfWeek[4] = { desc: "Qui", allowTimes: ['10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00'] };
dayOfWeek[5] = { desc: "Sex", allowTimes: ['11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00', '19:00'] };
dayOfWeek[6] = { desc: "Sáb" };

var data = new Date();

$.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt');
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   timepicker: dayOfWeek[data.getDay()].allowTimes ? true : false,
   allowTimes:dayOfWeek[data.getDay()].allowTimes
   ,
   onChangeDateTime:function(date,input){
      if(date){
         data = date;
         var d = data.getDay();
         this.setOptions({
            timepicker: dayOfWeek[d].allowTimes ? true : false,
            allowTimes: dayOfWeek[d].allowTimes
         });
         
         if(!dayOfWeek[d].allowTimes){
            input.val(input.val().match(/^.{10}/)[0]); // retorna os 10 primeiros caracteres
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-f0tzWhCwVFS3WeYaofoLWkTP62ObhewQ1EZn65oSYDZUg1+CyywGKkWzm8BxaJj5HGKI72PnMH9jYyIFz+GH7g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-AIOTidJAcHBH2G/oZv9viEGXRqDNmfdPVPYOYKGy3fti0xIplnlgMHUGfuNRzC6FkzIo0iIxgFnr9RikFxK+sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: Muito obg mesmo, se pudesse seria possível desabilitar ou impossibilitar o click ou seleção dos dias que não tem horários, por exemplo da pra selecionar o domingo e o sábado, se houvesse um jeito deles nem aparecem seria perfeito, mais só de não ser possível selecionar ja ajuda muito também

Comment: Mas tem como desabilitar sábado e domingo. No link tem o código `onGenerate:function( ct ){
    $(this).find('.xdsoft_date.xdsoft_weekend').addClass('xdsoft_disabled');
  }` que faz isso.